# how to add slides on display in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i m trying to add number of slides per display.it show 4 number of slide.i tried adding .carousel-item class to css but it doesnt seems to work.all it does it displays last slide after the 4th slide.  tried changing lg-3 to lg-2 it shrinked the slide but dint added anything.

```js
$('#multi-carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('#multi-carousel .carousel-item').length;
    if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction == "left") {
                $('#multi-carousel .carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('#multi-carousel .carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('#multi-carousel .carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('#multi-carousel .carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    /* Show 4th slide on md if col-md-4*/
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active.col-md-4.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%; /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Show 3rd slide on sm if col-sm-6*/
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active.col-sm-6.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -50%; /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    /* show 2 items */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    #multi-carousel .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* farthest right hidden item must be also positioned for animations */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction */
    #multi-carousel .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
/* MD */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* show 3rd of 3 item slide */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
/* LG */
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    /* show 4th item */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    /* Show 5th slide on lg if col-lg-3 */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active.col-lg-3.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -25%; /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction //t - previous slide direction last item animation fix */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multi-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 active">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/3.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/4.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img4">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/5.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img5">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/6.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img6">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/7.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img7">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/8.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="img8">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev w-10" href="#multi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-2x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next w-10" href="#multi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-2x"></i></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

[this is how it comes after adding .carousel-item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5VhD.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the variable value of **itemsPerSlide** from '5' to '9'? Hope it works for you.

Comment: here is the link i found useful while trying out carousel:
1. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/
or you can try jQuery plugin to take care of everything for you:
2. https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Responsive-Multi-slide-Carousel-Plugin-jQuery-Multislider.html

Answer (score 0):

i tried adding

```css
#multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }

    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    /* Show 5th slide on lg if col-lg-3 */
    #multi-carousel .carousel-inner .active.col-lg-3.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -25%; /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

this part of code multiple times..this seems to do the trick but second last item is not animating properly.